# Libreoffice Writer lets the computer crash when editing the file properties

Tags: crash, libreoffice, file-properties, libreoffice-writer

In LibreOffice Writer (6.4.3.2 x64, Windows 10.0) I try to edit the file properties, particularly the custom properties. Trying anything (adding an attribute, deleting one, editing one) lets the computer crash with a blue screen. That happens when I click the save button in the *File Properties* dialog.

Details: 
error reason is igdkmd64.sys, stop code is PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONE_PAGED_AREA

I tried it with and without Java RE, both crashed.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

**Edit 2020-05-08:**

In Tools --> Options --> LibreOffice --> View --> GraphicsOutput the checkbox "Use OpenGL for all rendering" was checked. No more crashes if I uncheck it

Answer (score 0):

I had this same..
`Use OpenGL for all rendering` works.